# Groupby ID and Count of col1 and apply conditional filters on Count col and the col1 and return a value

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda, group-by

1. Pandas Group by ID and count of RAG_col
2. If RAG_Col = 'R' AND Count of RAG_Col value is >=2 return 'R'
   Similarly if RAG_Col = 'A' AND Count of RAG_Col value is >=2 return 'A'
   Similarly if RAG_Col = 'G'&'A'&'R' and Count of RAG_Col value is ==1 return 'A'
   else 'G'
   After applying groupby and conditional filters and count RAG_Col I should get Overall_ALL RAG for each unique ID

A = ID
B = RAG

```
df['Overall RAG] = df.groupby(['A','B'])['B'].count().reset_index(name = 'C').apply(lambda x: 'R' if x.B == 'R' & x.C>=2 else 'A' if x.B == 'A' & x.C>=2
else 'A' if x.B=='A' & x.B == 'G' & x.B=='R' & x.C == 1
else 'G'if x.B!='' & x.C == '')
```

But I'm getting the Inavlid syntax not able to apply these conditions using lambda expression using groupby

Comment: which language you're writing in?

Comment: Python language

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing samples of your input dataframe(s) and expected output so that we can better understand what you're trying to do.